# Instrumental for genitive construction

Tags: грамматика

In [a poem by Anna Akhmatova](https://www.culture.ru/poems/10138/menya-kak-reku), we read:

> В таком году произошло бы то-то,
> А в этом — это: ездить, видеть, думать,
> И вспоминать, и в новую любовь
> Входить, как в зеркало, с тупым сознаньем
> Измены и еще вчера не бывшей
> Морщинкой…

It was translated by Judith Hemschemeyer as follows:

> In this year, such and such would have happened,
> In that year - that: traveling, seeing, thinking
> And remembering, and entering into a new love
> As into a mirror, with dim awareness
> Of betrayal and of the wrinkle
> That wasn't there the day before.

I don't understand why we have морщинкой and not морщинки. Indeed, [морщинкой](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) is instrumental while измены is genitive: I would have expected the genitive because I thought измены and морщинкой should be instances of а genitive construction of сознаньем (like the translation "betrayal" and "wrinkle" are genitive constructions of "awareness"). So, my question is: why do we have морщинкой and not морщинки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The translation doesn't convey the Russian meaning precisely.

Literally, it's "to enter into a new love, as into a mirror, with dull awareness of infidelity and a wrinkle that wasn't there the day before". It's "enter with a wrinkle", not "enter with awareness of the wrinkle".

*Морщинкой*, as well as *сознаньем*, are in the instrumental because that's what the preposition *с* governs when it means *with*.